# Get next and previous primary keys that match a pattern

Tags: mysql

I have a database similar to the following...

```
ID    ! Value 
...
654 ! Blue
656 ! Green
659 ! Blue
665 ! Blue
...
```

I have the value of a numerical primary key. I'm wanting to do a query that pulls the previous and next primary keys that match a pattern.

For example, I have ID 659, I want to do something like

```
SELECT NEXT, PREV FROM TABLE WHERE VALUE = 'Blue';
```

And I'm trying to do it efficiently instead of fetching the whole table.

Comment: Unfortunately, MySQL does not support windowing functions (which would make this task efficient and easy to code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 row and 2 columns:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT ID FROM test WHERE ID < 659 AND Value = 'Blue' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1) AS PREV,
  (SELECT ID FROM test WHERE ID > 659 AND Value = 'Blue' ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1) AS NEXT;
```

2 rows and 1 column:

```
(SELECT ID AS PREV FROM test WHERE ID < 659 AND Value = 'Blue' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT ID AS NEXT FROM test WHERE ID > 659 AND Value = 'Blue' ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: Did you meant `SELECT MAX(ID) AS PREV....` and `SELECT MIN(ID) AS NEXT...`?

Comment: @BobJarvis No, not `MAX` and `MIN`. He just want the values before and after a specific value.

Answer (score 2):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T (ID INT PRIMARY KEY,VAL VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO T (ID,VAL) VALUES (654,'BLUE'),(656,'GREEN'),(659,'BLUE'),(665,'BLUE');

SELECT CURRENT.ID CURRENTID,CURRENT.VAL,
        (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM T NEXT WHERE NEXT.ID > CURRENT.ID AND NEXT.VAL = CURRENT.VAL) NEXT,
        (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM T PREV WHERE PREV.ID < CURRENT.ID AND PREV.VAL = CURRENT.VAL) PREV
FROM T CURRENT;

+-----------+-------+------+------+
| CURRENTID | VAL   | NEXT | PREV |
+-----------+-------+------+------+
|       654 | BLUE  |  659 | NULL |
|       656 | GREEN | NULL | NULL |
|       659 | BLUE  |  665 |  654 |
|       665 | BLUE  | NULL |  659 |
+-----------+-------+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Or less elegantly (can't say about performance)

```
SELECT CURRENT.ID CURRENTID,CURRENT.VAL,
         NEXT.ID NEXTID,PREV.ID PREVID
FROM
(
SELECT T.ID, T.VAL, IF(T.VAL<>@P,@RN:=1,@RN:=@RN+1) RN, @P:=T.VAL
 FROM T,(SELECT @RN:=0,@P:=0) R
 ORDER BY T.VAL,T.ID
 ) CURRENT
 LEFT JOIN
 (
SELECT T.ID, T.VAL, IF(T.VAL<>@P1,@RN1:=1,@RN1:=@RN1+1) RN1, @P1:=T.VAL
 FROM T,(SELECT @RN1:=0,@P1:=0) R1
 ORDER BY T.VAL,T.ID
 ) NEXT ON NEXT.VAL = CURRENT.VAL AND NEXT.RN1 = CURRENT.RN + 1
 LEFT JOIN
 (
SELECT T.ID, T.VAL, IF(T.VAL<>@P2,@RN2:=1,@RN2:=@RN2+1) RN2, @P2:=T.VAL
 FROM T,(SELECT @RN2:=0,@P2:=0) R2
 ORDER BY T.VAL,T.ID
 ) PREV ON PREV.VAL = CURRENT.VAL AND PREV.RN2 = CURRENT.RN - 1
 ;

+-----------+-------+--------+--------+
| CURRENTID | VAL   | NEXTID | PREVID |
+-----------+-------+--------+--------+
|       654 | BLUE  |    659 |   NULL |
|       659 | BLUE  |    665 |    654 |
|       665 | BLUE  |   NULL |    659 |
|       656 | GREEN |   NULL |   NULL |
+-----------+-------+--------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: second option looks really large. I'm wondering maybe there's some inobvious advantages for such approach? could you say if there is something?

Comment: You could do n-1 and n+2 for example - not much value in your question I'll grant you..